# Как на андроид выполнять функцию каждые 30 сек?

Tags: android, java, многопоточность

Добрый день.
Вопрос как сделать так чтобы функция например my_func() выполнялась каждые 30 сек, и так же каждые 30 сек отправлялись мои текущие координаты?
Спасибо!

Comment: Нужно чтобы функция работала и в спящем режиме или только в активном состоянии? Исполнение зависит в т.ч. и от этого.

Comment: Нет только когда основная активность открыта!

Comment: Ну тогда любой Runnable/Thread подойдет - например как описано ниже у @falstaf

Comment: Да это понятно! А как их получать каждые 30 секунд?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
}, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: А как быть с координатами?

Comment: [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html][1]. А вообще, это стоит сделать отдельным вопросом. 

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: В спящем состоянии - это работать не будет.

Comment: Про спящее состояние в вопросе ни слова. А так да, для этого есть `AlarmManager`.

Comment: У меня каждые 30 сек должен обновляться список по полученным данным, но ни черта не происходит. Ставлю adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() тоже не работает. Координаты отправлять каждые 30 сек тоже не получается!

Comment: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Вот что мне говорит log.

Comment: Ну и правильно говорит - это означает, что вы из другого треда пытаетесь изменить поведение юай элемента.

P.S. Надеюсь вы поняли что я написал. Если нет - сожалею...

Comment: Да я Вам это и написал! Зачем Вы мне это превели я не понял! Я имел ввиду как сделать так чтобы список обновлялся каждые 30 сек? 

@falstaf как это сделать? Handler/runOnUiThread не получается?

Comment: @ilyarasputin, поменьше экспрессии, не стоит злоупотреблять восклицательными знаками. Что вам ещё не понятно? Для взаимодействия другого потока с UI вы можете использовать `Handler`/`runOnUiThread`/etc.

Comment: О, @falstaf, интересный способ вы предложили. А чем, кстати, Timer в отдельном потоке не подходит?

Comment: Из документации на `Timer`:

> Timers schedule one-shot or recurring tasks for execution. *Prefer ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for new code.*