# Проверять состояние GPS по таймеру

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `BroadcastReceiver` который оповещает мой `Service` при включении/отключении `GPS`:

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        IGpsStatusListener iGpsStatusListener = (IGpsStatusListener) context;

        if (intent.getAction().matches(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                if (!(MyApplication.isMyServiceRunning(context, LocationService.class))) {
                    iGpsStatusListener.gpsLocationIsTurnOn();
                }
            } else {
                if (!(MyApplication.isMyServiceRunning(context, LocationService.class))) {
                    iGpsStatusListener.gpsLocationIsTurnOff();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`LocationService` реализовывает `IGpsStatusListener`

Но проблема в том, что `Receiver` оповещает только в том случае, если состояние `GPS` изменился, но мне нужно, чтобы проверял каждые 10 секунд.

Вопрос: Как проверять состояние `GPS` по таймеру?

Comment: Логично предположить, что если состояние не изменилось, то оно равно предыдущему. И так каждые 10 секунд, пока оно не изменится. Или проблема в том, что вы не можете узнать первоначальное состояние до первого изменения? Тогда причём тут 10 секунд?

Comment: @eugeneek, В самом начале я предлагаю включить и вывожу диалоговое окно. Если он не включил, то каждые 10 секунд проверяю и показываю Уведомление(Notification)

Comment: Если состояние не изменилось (Receiver не сработал), значит gps не включили. Получается весь вопрос сводится к тому, как выполнять опрделённый код каждые 10 секунд?

Comment: Да, так и есть.

Comment: [Как на андроид выполнять функцию каждые 30 сек?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/260403/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B5-30-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Comment: @eugeneek, Да я знаю как работать с таймерами. Вопрос о том как это делать в BroadcastReceiver который срабатывает при регистрировании Receiver и при изменениях состояния GPS.